# Assign a value to global variable inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem assigning a value to a global variable and using it inside of a function. Here is my code:

```
var chartinfo = {"c0":"0", "c1":"0"}; // This is my global variable
$.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8080/chartinfo", function(json1){
    chartinfo = json1; // I need to assign json1's value to chartinfo
});
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("external chartinfo " + chartinfo.c0.name); // I need to use chartinfo here
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? What happens when you run the code? I believe it's that you are accessing `chartinfo` before it was changed. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/218196. Also, nesting two `ready` event handlers doesn't add any benefit.

Comment: Is it alerting 0?  Felix is probably right document.ready is executing before the getJSON callback is executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alert fails because your request is not finished yet. You could try this:

```
var chartinfo = {
    "c0": "0",
    "c1": "0"
};

var jqxhr = $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8080/chartinfo", function (json1) {
    console.log("success");
})
    .done(function () {
    chartinfo = json1;
    alert("external chartinfo " + chartinfo.c0.name); // I need to use chartinfo here
})
    .fail(function () {
    console.log("error");
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZpUsM/